# ARKit - How to get the specific node in sceneview?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm new in ARKit. I want to get a specific node in sceneview to interactive with that node. This is my code:

```
@objc func moveNode(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if !isRotating{

        //1. Get The Current Touch Point
        let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)

        //2. Get The Next Feature Point Etc
        guard let hitTest = self.sceneView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }

        //3. Convert To World Coordinates
        let worldTransform = hitTest.worldTransform

        //4. Set The New Position
        let newPosition = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y, worldTransform.columns.3.z)

        //5. Apply To The Node
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes{ (node, _) in
            //**********************************************************
            // how to detect which node is active to interactive here???
            node.simdPosition = float3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z)
            //**********************************************************
        }
    }
}
```

How to detect which node is active to interactive in ** code block? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get a reference to a specific `SCNNode` you need to make us of an SCNHitTest which:

> Looks for SCNGeometry objects along the ray you specify. For each
>   intersection between the ray and and a geometry, SceneKit creates a
>   hit-test result to provide information about both the SCNNode object
>   containing the geometry and the location of the intersection on the
>   geometry’s surface.

Lets assume therefore that in your scene you have two SCNode variables e.g:

```
var nodeOne: SCNNode!
var nodeTwo: SCNNode!
```

And that these are initialised with a unique `name` property:

```
let nodeOneGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2)
nodeOneGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
nodeOne = SCNNode(geometry: nodeOneGeometry)
nodeOne.name = "Node One"
nodeOne.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)
augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeOne)

let nodeTwoGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)
nodeTwoGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
nodeTwo = SCNNode(geometry: nodeTwoGeometry)
nodeTwo.name = "Node Two"
nodeTwo.position = SCNVector3(0.5, 0, -1.5)
augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeTwo)
```

We also need to create another variable to store the current node e.g:

```
var currentNode: SCNNode?
```

Which we will use in your existing function like so:

```
@objc func moveNode(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    //1. Get The Current Touch Point
    let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

    //2. If The Gesture State Has Begun Perform A Hit Test To Get The SCNNode At The Touch Location
    if gesture.state == .began{

        //2a. Perform An SCNHitTest To Detect If An SCNNode Has Been Touched
        guard let nodeHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, options: nil).first else { return }

        //2b. Get The SCNNode Result
        let nodeHit = nodeHitTest.node

        //2c. Get The Namt Of The Node & Set As The Current Node
        if let nodeName = nodeHit.name{

            if nodeName == "Node One"{

                print("Node One Hit")
                currentNode = nodeHit

            }else if nodeName == "Node Two"{

                print("Node Two Hit")
                currentNode = nodeHit

            }else{
                return
            }
        }
    }

    //3. If The Gesture State Has Changed Then Perform An ARSCNHitTest To Detect Any Existing Planes
    if gesture.state == .changed{

        //3b. Get The Next Feature Point Etc
        guard let hitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }

        //3c. Convert To World Coordinates
        let worldTransform = hitTest.worldTransform

        //3d. Set The New Position
        let newPosition = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y, worldTransform.columns.3.z)

        //3e. Apply To The Node
        currentNode?.simdPosition = float3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z)

    }

    //4. If The Gesture State Has Ended Remove The Reference To The Current Node
    if gesture.state == .ended{
        currentNode = nil
    }
}
```

Please note that there are many different ways to achieve what you need, and that this is just one of them. Hope it helps...

**Update:**

If you don't have a name for your SCNNode or perhaps they have the same name (don't see why they would though) you can simply modify the function like so:

```
@objc func moveNode(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

//1. Get The Current Touch Point
let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView)

//2. If The Gesture State Has Begun Perform A Hit Test To Get The SCNNode At The Touch Location
if gesture.state == .began{

    //2a. Perform An SCNHitTest To Detect If An SCNNode Has Been Touched
    guard let nodeHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, options: nil).first else { return }

    //2b. Get The SCNNode Result
    let nodeHit = nodeHitTest.node

    //2c. Set As The Current Node
    currentNode = nodeHit

}

//3. If The Gesture State Has Changed Then Perform An ARSCNHitTest To Detect Any Existing Planes
if gesture.state == .changed{

    //3b. Get The Next Feature Point Etc
    guard let hitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }

    //3c. Convert To World Coordinates
    let worldTransform = hitTest.worldTransform

    //3d. Set The New Position
    let newPosition = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y, worldTransform.columns.3.z)

    //3e. Apply To The Node
    currentNode?.simdPosition = float3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z)

}

//4. If The Gesture State Has Ended Remove The Reference To The Current Node
if gesture.state == .ended{
    currentNode = nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JoshRobbins, but what happen if I have two node with the same name? How can detect it? Thank you

Comment: Why would they have the same name? You can just provide them with a different one :)

Comment: Because my situation is the node will be download from server and it has the same node name on server so I cannot change it. So I want to detect node without using the name but I don't know how :(

Comment: I think that’s not correct... they may have the same file name but when you download it you can change the name property :)

Comment: Ohh it's working perfect in your update code!! Thank you very much @JOshRobbins <3